# HTML and Javascript Form not calculating on submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, calculated-field

I'm new to coding. I'm having an issue with a form not returning a calculated value and I'm not sure what I did wrong. When I press submit nothing happens. I don't see any linting errors. A brief red pops up in the dev tools on chrome but not long enough for me to read the error.

HTML:

```
<body>

  <form id="load-calculator">
    <p>
      <label for="performer-mass">Please Enter Performer(s) Weight (lbs)</label>
      <input id="performer-mass" required name="performer-mass" type="number" min="1">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="apparatus-mass">Please Enter Apparatus Weight (lbs)</label>
      <input id="apparatus-mass" required name="apparatus-mass" type="number" min="1">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="dynamic-factor">Please Choose An Apparatus <br>(Dynamic Adjustment Factor)</label>
      <select id="dynamic-factor" required name="dynamic-factor">
        <option value="1.5">Aerial Yoga (1.5)</option>
        <option value="2">Silks (2 for drops less than 3ft.)</option>
        <option value="3">Static Trapeze (3)</option>
        <option value="3">silks (3 for drops 3-8ft.)</option>
        <option value="5">Rope (5)</option>
        <option value="5">Straps (5)</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" onClick="characteristicLoad" value="Calculate">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="result">Estimated Characteristic Load</label>
      <input for="load-calculator" id="result">
    </p>
  </form>

  <script type="module" src="src/loadCalculator.js"></script>

</body>
```

Javascript:

```
export function characteristicLoad() {
  const performerMass = document.getElementById('performer-mass').value;
  const apparatusMass = document.getElementById('apparatus-mass').value;
  const totalMass = performerMass + apparatusMass;

  const dynamicFactor = document.getElementById('dynamic-factor').value;

  let result = document.getElementById('result');

  let characteristicLoad = totalMass * dynamicFactor * 6;
  result.value = characteristicLoad;
}
```

Here is a link to a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dylancorvidae/ae289qum/1/

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Change your input type from `submit` to `button` to prevent actually submitting the form, and make sure to call your function by adding parentheses behind the function name.

The corrected "Calculate" button looks like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="characteristicLoad()" value="Calculate">
```

<sup>**Note:** If you actually *do* want to submit the form after the calculation, you can keep the input type as `submit` and bind to the `onsubmit` event instead of the `onclick` event.</sup>

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
function characteristicLoad() {
  const performerMass = document.getElementById('performer-mass').value;
  const apparatusMass = document.getElementById('apparatus-mass').value;
  const totalMass = performerMass + apparatusMass;

  const dynamicFactor = document.getElementById('dynamic-factor').value;

  let result = document.getElementById('result');

  let characteristicLoad = totalMass * dynamicFactor * 6;
  result.value = characteristicLoad;
}
```

```html
<form id="load-calculator">
  <p>
    <label for="performer-mass">Please Enter Performer(s) Weight (lbs)</label>
    <input id="performer-mass" required name="performer-mass" type="number" min="1">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="apparatus-mass">Please Enter Apparatus Weight (lbs)</label>
    <input id="apparatus-mass" required name="apparatus-mass" type="number" min="1">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="dynamic-factor">Please Choose An Apparatus <br>(Dynamic Adjustment Factor)</label>
    <select id="dynamic-factor" required name="dynamic-factor">
      <option value="1.5">Aerial Yoga (1.5)</option>
      <option value="2">Silks (2 for drops less than 3ft.)</option>
      <option value="3">Static Trapeze (3)</option>
      <option value="3">silks (3 for drops 3-8ft.)</option>
      <option value="5">Rope (5)</option>
      <option value="5">Straps (5)</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" onClick="characteristicLoad()" value="Calculate">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="result">Estimated Characteristic Load</label>
    <input for="load-calculator" id="result">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for this great answer.  Unfortunately it's not working in vscode for some reason. I keep getting this error in chrome dev console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: characteristicLoad is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick "

Comment: Means that your JavaScript is not properly loaded. (Note that I stripped the `script` tag off my HTML because it's automatically loaded by the snippet.)

Comment: I did notice that and used my script tag  <script type="module" src="src/loadCalculator.js"></script>  That is the correct file path because when I click on it in vscode it opens the right file. I normally place my scripts at the bottom of my body but for some reason it's not working still. And I tried moving outside of body and in the head. Googling to see if there is something out there that might help.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has error at  the `onclick` event of button.

You have to need use `()` after the function name like this: 
`onClick="characteristicLoad()"`